# Spearman's Rank Correlation Tests and Independent Sample t-test

Tags: regression, correlation, t-test, spearman-rho

If I would like to select which variables should I include in the logistic regression model, should I do a correlation test first or a t-test?

Also, for Spearman's Rank Correlation Test, do I need to include the outcome variable (categorical items) in it?

Comment: Frame challenge (i.e. herein I challenge your premises): Let's start in the regression context, because it's simpler. Look at the topmost diagram here in the Wikipedia article on [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox). Imagine that the red points were moved somewhat up and to the right (while remaining parallel with the blue ones), enough that the black line was closer to flat. ... ctd

Comment: ... Can you see that it's perfectly possible for both the IVs in that plot (the x-axis variable and the red-blue one) to be effectively unrelated to y when fitted alone, even though there's a really strong relationship when both are together? In regression this is a result of what's called *omitted-variable bias* (which also has a Wikipedia article but without a nice motivating drawing). The same thing can happen in GLMs - or indeed many other kinds of models - including binomial regression models. How can a one-variable-at-a-time selection strategy avoid this problem?

Comment: A second form of frame challenge would question it from the point of view that you're selecting variables by looking at the same data you're then going to be performing inference on; this impacts the properties of your later inference (estimation, testing, CIs, etc). This is somewhat related to the issues discussed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data . This problem is somewhat more avoidable (e.g. by data splitting for example). Model choice is not such a simple task as just doing a series of univariate tests.